# is it advisable to save documents in iis application hosted folder?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis

is it advisable to save documents in IIS application hosted folder..
i am saving documents of invoice(and others docs) in my application hosted folder using(example)

```
 var fname = context.Server.MapPath("~/Docs/" + file.FileName);
    file.SaveAs(fname);
```

will that impact on application loading..?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No It should not be in application hosted folder. For that we make a Virtual Directory under your hosted site in IIS and make its physical path to a common file server which is accessible from your Hosted Server. For Production some organization use third party document server like Amazon S3. Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

No It will not affect to application performance until it consume more disk space. But it's better to have separate virtual directory for such static resource. It will also help at time of maintainers of the application.